# Implementing an affine type system

Tags: type-systems, hindley-milner, linear-types

In an affine type system, resources can be used at most once.

Starting from a Hindley-Milner type system, it seems that a simple way to enforce affinity is to simply remove a variable from the current typing context whenever the typing rule for variables is used (as these [slides](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psxld/awayday2011/slides/ial_slides.pdf) on LinearML suggest, on page 15).

Is this all there is to enforcing affinity? Or is there anything more complex to do?